# Passing function as parameter to call on an object

Tags: functional-programming, java-8

Is it possible to implement it in Java 8

instead of:

```
public void changeObject(int id) {    
        MyObject object= repository.findOne(id);
        if(object!= null) {
            object.setAttribute(true);
            repository.save(object);
        }            
    }
```

using something like:

```
doOperationOnItem(id,MyObject::setAttribute(true));

private void doOperationOnObject(int id, Function function) {
    resolve(()->repository.findOne(id)).ifPresent(item-> {
        function.callOn(item)
        repository.save(item);
    });
}
```

Comment: Why don’t you let the [existing API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-) inspire you? See also [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-)[et](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#thenAccept-java.util.function.Consumer-)[c.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) But `MyObject::setAttribute(true)` doesn’t work, use `o -> o.setAttribute(true)`

Comment: ah yes. I think I just overcomplicated it a bit, your suggestion is working, thanks

Answer (score 1):

For your reference:

```
Optional.ofNullable(repository.findOne(id)).map(object -> object.ofAttribute(true))
                                           .ifPresent(object -> repository.save(object));
```

As you can see, there should add a new method which modify the attribute value and return this object in Class `MyObject` , like this below:

```
public class MyObject{
    private Boolean attribute;

    // new method
    public MyObject ofAttribute(Boolean attribute){
         this.attribute = attribute;
         return this;
    }
}
```

And if there are other code's pattern like your example, you can write a common pattern with Java 8, just like this:

```
public void changeObject(int id, Function<MyObject, MyObject> ... fun) {    
// the param fun is a array of Function, and use the method Stream.reduce and 
// Function::andThen to make these functions to a one function one by one
Optional.ofNullable(repository.findOne(id)).map(Stream.of(fun).reduce(Function::andThen).get())
                                                   .ifPresent(item -> repository.save(item));


}
```

So use this patter, your example change into this way:

```
xxx.changeObject(12, object -> object.ofAttribute(true))
```

And now you can update more than one attribute with this pattern:

```
xxx.changeObject(12, object -> object.ofAttribute(true), object -> object.ofAttribute1('Java'), Object -> object.ofAttribute2(1));
```

Finally, don't forget to add new methods `ofAttribute1` and `ofAttribute2` if you want to use this pattern. :)